# How can I create recursive generator in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

For example, I want to write a generator to iterate a tree. Can I use recursive function call?

```
Iterator<node> forallchildren(node) {
    for (var n in node.children) {
       yield n;
       forallchildren(n);
    }
}
```

Looks like the recursive call only generate iterator but not act like traverse the tree.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `yield` in a function returning `Iterable` (not `Iterator`) if you mark the function with `sync*`.

Moreover to yield elements from an `Iterable` you have to use `yield*`.

So you can write your code like:

```
Iterable<Node> forallchildren(Node node) sync* {
    for (var n in node.children) {
       yield n;
       yield* forallchildren(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked again. It is on the language tour page too.